# Center Drawable and Text in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable

I want to make drawable and text center in my EditText. The text is centered but the drawable is not. I want something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PMem.jpg

Please help. This is what I have done so far

```
 <EditText 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lol2"
    />
```

When the user types in something in the EditText, the drawable should move itself to the left if the text is lenghty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchET"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="75dp"
    android:paddingEnd="75dp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint=" Username"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/your_icon"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"/>
```

The kicker here is that you wrap_content for the width, align the text however, center the view however you'd like, then add padding to each end of the edit text.

This shoves the drawable to the start of your text but still lets you expand your edit text background.

Answer (score 2):

instead of

> android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lol2"

try using

> android:drawableStart="@drawable/lol2"

Answer (score 0):

Basically gravity attribute is used to apply changes of aligning the contents of lay out so you can put the gravity to center to align contents in center and center_vertical to to align contents on left side and gravity to center_horizontal to put contents in horizontal center. i.e

```
android:gravity="center"
```